# Запятая перед КАК в предложении

Tags: как

В предложении «Провожали нас как родных» нужна запятая?

Answer (score 1):

***Провожали нас как родных.***

Оборот не обособляется, так как имеет значение приравнивания (к родным),  отождествления (с родными).

http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=125#pp125

§ 90. Обороты со сравнительными союзами (частицами) как, словно, будто, точно, как будто, что не выделяются запятыми в следующих случаях:

а) при сказуемом, требующем конкретизации (оборот имеет **значение отождествления или приравнивания)**: Вот почему она смотрела на землю как на юдоль скорби (Нов.-Пр.); **Она воспринимала мать как старшую сестру**; ..Любое служебное поручение в то время воспринималось как выполнение священного Революционного Долга (Кат.);

Answer (score 0):

Не нужна запятая.

Вопрос № 281427 (gramota.ru)

Детский сад нам (,) как родной. Нужна ли запятая?

Ответ справочной службы русского языка

**Запятая не нужна.**

Примеры из книг:

*Замечательные марокканцы встретили нас как родных.*

*Отец Ларисы принял нас как родных!*

*Нельзя сказать, что экипаж корабля принял нас как родных, но явных протестов не возникло.*